# Infinite solutions to a function.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have rewritten this question.

Take a series,
$$
S_k = \sum_{n=1}^k u_n
$$
where $S_k \in \mathbb{C}$ forms a divergent series as $k \to \infty$. Now take a function $f_n(x)$ such that there are infinite roots of this function wherein each successive root (these are the only roots to the equation) is the next term in the series $S_k$,
$$
f_n(x) = (x-S_1)(x-S_2)(x-S_3)\dots .
$$
Apart from the trivial cases whereby we just increase the power or change the coefficient such that, 
$$
f_n(x) = i_0 \cdot (x-S_1)^{i_1}(x-S_2)^{i_2}(x-S_3)^{i_3}\dots 
$$
are there any other functions that cross these points exclusively.

Comment: There are obviously an infinite number of curves that fit such a description because the points that are not equal to $0$ can take any value.

Comment: That's why I said to ignore constants, which is what I think you're referring to but I'm not sure.

Comment: What you are saying is indeed unclear.  Your $S_n$ only seems to be defined for positive integers and takes positive values unbounded above (though perhaps $S_0=0$).  It is also unclear whether the second part of the question is related to the first, or whether your functions are supposed to be continuous or series

Comment: @Henry I meant to put $\infty$ not $k$ sorry, and the function $f(x)$ should be continuous everywhere.

Comment: I think you mean $S_n = \sum_\limits{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ and then $S_n$ are the partial sums of the Harmonic series.

Comment: You could also multiply by a never-zero function such as $e^x$.

Comment: Well since we are dealing with infinities, $-\infty$ is a solution to this function, hence adding another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description I think you want to define some sequence
$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k$$
and then have a function $f(z)$ with roots at every $z=a_n$. We can take
$$f_n(z)=(z-a_1)(z-a_2)\dots(z-a_{n-1})(z-a_n)$$
Then the function $f(z)$ can defined by
$$f(z)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(z)$$
which gives a continuous definition of $f(z)$ for any sequence $a_n$ which diverges to $\pm\infty$. But if $a_n$ converges to some value $L\in\mathbb{R}$, then such a function $f(z)$ will be discontinuous at $z=L$ as $f(z)$ will have infinite roots in the neighborhood of $z=L$.

Assuming that $a_n$ diverges, since the function $g(z)\cdot f(z)$ where $g(z)\gt0$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ has the same roots as $f(z)$ we can say that $g(z)\cdot f(z)$ is also a valid function that fits your description. For example, if we have $g(z)=e^{kz}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$ then we have an infinite number of valid functions that fit such a description.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my explanation of the problem. But for the second part, by including $g(x)$ you have added the solution $x = \sqrt{-1}$ which is not part of the series. I was talking about functions whose only solutions are those from the series. I'm going to make another edit.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to add the square root.

Comment: I think there are infinite solutions but only if you keep adding equivalent terms, as in you can only change the function $f_n(x)$ by increasing the power of any element, not by adding new terms.

Comment: But you added the solution $i$ to the function am I not incorrect?

Comment: Oh I should probably change the question again then.

Comment: In that case take $g(x)=e^{kx}$ where $k\in\mathbb{R}$ for an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Well you did add $-\infty$ to the solutions but yes I guess this works, thank you.